# XSD with dynamic element?

Tags: xml, xsd, xslt-1.0

I have an xml, one of the elements(dynamic1, dynamic2,dynamic3......dynamicN) keeps changing dynamically. How do i generate XSD to validate this kind of XML ?

I tried to use xs:any, but that's not working.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <dynamic1>
        <abc>B</abc>
        <xyz>10</xyz>
    </dynamic1>
    <dynamic2>
        <abc>B</abc>
        <xyz>10</xyz>
    </dynamic2>
        .
        .
        .
    <dynamic100>
        <abc>B</abc>
        <xyz>10</xyz>
    </dynamic100>
</root> 

<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
      <xs:element name="root">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="dynamic1">
              <xs:complexType>
                <xs:sequence>
                  <xs:element type="xs:string" name="abc"/>
                  <xs:element type="xs:byte" name="xyz"/>
                </xs:sequence>
              </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
    </xs:schema>
```

Comment: Is the `dynamic` set of elements fixed in size and known in advance?

Answer (score 1):

You can't (except perhaps with extreme use of assertions in XSD 1.1). XSD isn't designed to validate arbitrary XML, it's designed to validate the kind of XML that the designers of XSD thought you should be designing.